# Как передать условие в форматную строку?

Tags: python, строки

При решении одной из задач на checkio.org столкнулся с форматной строкой следующего вида. Код приведен полностью для контекста, интересует только форматная строка:

```
def time_converter(time):
   h, m = map(int, time.split(':'))
   return f"{(h-1)%12+1}:{m:02d} {'ap'[h>11]}.m."
```

Очень хочется понять принцип работы синтаксиса f-строк в контексте передачи условного выражения.

Может кого-нибудь уже заинтересовала такая тема и кто-нибудь находил "понятно описанные" ресурсы. Прошу поделиться.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В f-строках выполняется некий python код:

```
f"{(h-1)%12+1}:{m:02d} {'ap'[h>11]}.m."
```

И как я понимаю, вам интересно как работает строка `{'ap'[h>11]}`?

Внутри нее булевое выражение, чей результат передается в `'ap'[]`. `ap` это строка на два элемента. Булевое выражение в целочисленном эквиваленте равно: `True` = 1, а `False` = 0.

Поэтому, при `h > 11` будет вызвано `'ap'[True]`, что соответствует `'ap'[1]` и это вернет `'p'`.

Аналогом `{'ap'[h>11]}` будет выражение `{'ap'[1] if h > 11 else 'ap'[0]}`

Comment: Супер. Да, именно этот кусок кода меня и заинтересовал. Я думал - это некий такой синтаксис применимый к форматным строкам, все оказалось намного проще.

Answer (score 1):

Выражение `h>11` возвращает `True` или `False`. В контексте оператора индекса `[]` они трактуются как целые числа - `True` как 1 и `False` как 0. Соответственно выражение возвращает первый или второй символ строки "ap".

Comment: Немного меня опередили, буквально на 8 секунд :)

Comment: @gil9red надо в синхронные виды спорта подаваться, мы уже не первый раз так :)